# How to count how many duplicates an array has in Php

Tags: php, random, count

I'm new to Php and today I came across the rand()-function. I'd like to fill an array with numbers created with this function and then count the number of its duplicates. I already tried it a first time, but somehow I seem to be on the woodway.

```
<?php

$numbers = array();


for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    $numbers[$i] = rand(0, 100);
}

//$numbers = array(12,12,12,12);
echo "random numbers generated.<br>";

$arrLength = count($numbers);
$arrWithDoubles = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $arrLength; $i++) {
    //echo "start looping for i: ".$i."! numbers['i'] has the content".$numbers[$i].".<br>"; 
    for ($x=$i; $x < $arrLength; $x++) { 
            //echo "looped for x: ".$x."! numbers['x'] has the content".$numbers[$x].".<br>";
        if($numbers[$i] == $numbers[$x]) {
            if($i != $x) {
                //echo "pushed to 'arrWithDoubles'.<br>";
                array_push($arrWithDoubles, $numbers[$x]);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "numbers of doubles: ".count($arrWithDoubles)."<br>";
echo "list of numbers which were double:<br>";
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrWithDoubles); $i++) { 
    echo $arrWithDoubles[$i];
    echo "<br>";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: you should look into [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) also

Comment: Do you want to know how many times particular number is duplicated or just to know how many duplicates is at all?

Comment: just how many duplicates the array contains at all - but I want to be capable to list them (the duplicate numbers)

Comment: @bananatreedad: Define _"how many duplicates"_ `[1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` contains 4 duplicates for each of the values (1 and 2). do you want to know how many values have duplicates in the array, or do you want to know that this array contains 8 duplicate values?

Comment: You can remove dupliactes by `array_flip(array_flip($array));` or `array_unique($array)` and then count length of output array. `count($original_array) - count($without_duplicates_array)` gives you answer ;).

Comment: can't you just check that the number doesn't exist before you add it to the array to avoid duplication in the first place.

Comment: One way check it before add to array, if that already exist using in_array. If you want to remove duplicates use  array_unique($numbers);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your input. With that I came to the following solution which fits my demand the best:

```
<?php

function countValueInArray($value, $array) {
    $count = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
        if($value == $array[$i]) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

$numbers = array();

for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    $numbers[$i] = rand(0, 100);
}

$duplicates = array();
for ($x=0; $x < count($numbers); $x++) { 
    $number = countValueInArray($numbers[$x], $numbers);

    if ($number > 1) {
        array_push($duplicates, $numbers[$x]);
    }
}

$duplicatesList = array_values(array_unique($duplicates));

echo "number of duplicates: ".count($duplicatesList);
echo "<br>these are: <br>";

print_r($duplicatesList);

?>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `array_unique()` function removes duplicates from an array, then just add a bit of math.

```
<?php

$numberOfDuplicates = count($orginalArray) - (count($orginalArray) - count(array_unique($originalArray)));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$origin = array(2,4,5,4,6,2);
$count_origin = count($origin);
$unique = array_unique($origin);
$count_unique = count($unique);

$duplicates = $count_origin - $count_unique;

echo $duplicates;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = array();
foreach ($srcRandom as $sr) {
    if (!array_key_exists ($sr, $count) ) {
        $count[$sr] = 1;
        continue;
    }
    $count[$sr]++;
}
var_dump ($count);
```